# Counting edges in a finite connected graph where each vertex is exactly one of two values.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

Let $p,q$ and $r$ be positive integers greater than $0$ with $q\neq r$. Suppose that $H$ is a finite connected graph without loops or multiedges on $p$ vertices with $q$ vertices of degree $r$, $r$ vertices of degree $q$ and $p =q+r$. I use the following notation: $V,E$ and $F$ are the number of points, edges and faces of $H$ respectively. By $deg(v)$ we mean the degree or valency of any vertex in $H$.

***claim***: $H$ has $qr$ edges

***proof***: If $V(r)$ and $V(q)$ are the set of vertices with degrees $r$ and $q$ respectively then $V(r) \cap V(q) = \emptyset$. Consequently $|V| = |V(r)\cup V(q)| = |V(r)| + |V(q)|$. Now, from Euler we know that $2|E| = \sum_{ v\in H} deg(v)$. In particular we can write

\begin{align}
2|E|  
= \sum_{v\in V(r)}deg(v)+\sum_{v\in V(q)}deg(v)  =\underbrace{(r+\ldots+r)}_{q}+\underbrace{(q+\ldots+q)}_{r}  
= qr+rq
 =2rq. \end{align}

And that establishes the claim. $\blacksquare$

First I want to make sure that the above proof is correct. Note that $H$ is not necessarily bipartite! Then I have this question.

***Question_1*** For which pair $(q,r)$ can $H$ be planar.  I suspect we have the following planar pairs: $(1,r)$, $(2,r)$, $(3,r)$,$(4,r)$ and $(5,r)$. In the case of $(5,r)$ I believe that $r=1,2,3$ or $4$.

Comment: What are the "faces" of a graph that might not be planar? For example, $K_{q,r}$ satisfies your condition, but is not planar for $q,r\geq 3$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks I will correct my question!

Comment: And yes, your above proof in the first part is fine.

Comment: A graph with $q=2$ would be a graph with two nodes, $a,b$, of valence $r$. There are $r$ nodes of valence $2$, so there are only two such graphs - where $a,b$ is an edge and where $a,b$ is not an edge. When $a,b$ is not an edge, each valency $2$ point is joined to each of $a,b$. If $a,b$ is an edge, then there $r-2$ valency $2$ points are joined to $a,b$ and the last $2$, $x,y$ are joined together, and $x$ is joined to $a$, $y$ joined to $b$. It's not hard to prove both of these cases are planar.

Comment: Yeah I figure for $q=2$ there are only two family of graphs namely $K_{2,r}$ and a second call it $G$ that you described above. I suspect there are infinitely many $r$ such that $H(3,r)$ is planar.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews we can use the fact in planar graphs $E \leq 3V-6$. So with substitution $qr \leq 3q+3r-6$ Now for every $q$ this is true when $r=1$. This would be the graphs $K_{1,r}$. Suppose that $q=5$. Then in order for $H(2,5)$ to be planar $5r \leq 3(r+3)$ which is true for $r = 1,2,3$ and $4$? I can draw at least one planar $H(5,3)$ and $H(5,4)$

Comment: You can write that inequality as $(q-3)(r-3)\leq 3$.  That greatly restricts $r,q$. In particular, there won't be any with $r>6$ except when $q\leq 3$. When $r=6$, you might find cases where $q=3,4$. When $r=5$ you can only have $q\leq 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no graph with $q=3$ and $r>8$.

If there was, then let $v_1,v_2,v_3$ be the three points of valence $r$ and $S$ be the $r$ points of valency $3$. Then how many points of $S$ are connected to only two of $v_1,v_2,v_3?$

The number of edges between $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and $S$ is at least $3(r-2)$. If $r>8$ then $3(r-2)>2r+2$. That means at least three nodes of $S$ must be connected to all three nodes of $v_1,v_2,v_3$. That means that we have $K_{3,3}$ as a subgraph.

If $(q,r)=(3,8)$, then $v_1,v_2,v_3$ have to all be joined, and there must be two $s_1,s_2\in S$ that must be joined to all $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

Every other node in $S$ must be joined with one other node in $S$ to get the
valency of $3$.

Adding that to the fact that you've shown that $(q-3)(r-3)\leq 3$, and found cases where $(q,r)=(3,4),(4,5),(3,5),(4,6)$, you are left to search for $(q,r)=(3,6),(3,7)$ and $(3,8)$.

I think I've constructed a case where $(q,r)=(3,8)$. Make $v_1,v_2,v_3$ a triangle. Add $s_1$ to the center and connect to each of $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Add squares to the exterior of each triangle, drawing a complete $K_4$ for each square. Then add $s_2$ to the exterior and connect to each of the $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

I suspect this graph is unique.

You can get cases $(q,r)=(3,7)$ and $(3,6)$ by dropping one or both of $s_1,s_2,$ respectively.

Comment: I can draw $(3,4)$ several of them actually. Also I can draw a $(3,5)$ and a $(4,6)$. @ThomasAndrews would you agree that the only infinite family of planar H-graphs is then $H(2,r)$

Comment: Well, there can only be finitely many for each $(q,r)$, and so the only infinite family are the ones where $q=2$, since for $q>2$ we have shown there are only finitely many possible $r$

Comment: By the way, your notation $H(2,r)$ for family with $q=2$ is confusing. Just call it $H(q)$, not $H(q,r)$, because it feels like $H(q,r)$ would mean the family of such graphs with $q,r$ fixed, not just $q$ fixed. @AnthonyHernandez

Comment: ^ Done I will correct that and update the notation.

Comment: I've found a graph for $(q,r)=(3,8)$. @AnthonyHernandez

Comment: There's no error - I said there is no such graph with $q=3$ and $r>8$. @AnthonyHernandez

Comment: OK cool what does it look like just curious.

Comment: I added it to my answer @AnthonyHernandez

Comment: I take it the Soifer graph is a chordal (4,5) is an example also. Not sure if it is unique. [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SoiferGraph.html)

Comment: You can get cases $(3,6)$ and $(3,7)$ by dropping one or both of $s_1,s_2$ from my $(3,8)$ example. so I think you can find a graph whenever $(r-3)(q-3)\leq 3$. and, if $r$ or $q=3$ then the other is $\leq 8$.

Comment: Got it. To recap there are two infinite families ($1,r)$ and $(2,r)$. Then we have 7 finite families $(3,4)$, $(3,5)$, $(3,6)$, $(3,7)$, $(3,8)$, $(4,5)$, and ($4,6)$. Also you used Kuratowski's theorem in your answer above? Namely $H(3)$ is not planar whenever $r>8$ since it would have a $K_{3,3}$ minor. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Not even a minor, it would have a subgraph isomorphic to $K_{3,3}$. But yes, I'm using that theorem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37374/discussion-between-anthony-hernandez-and-thomas-andrews).